# I am trying to create a recursive function for identifying palindromes in python

Tags: python, function, recursion, palindrome

I have written this code so far:

```
def palindrome(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return False
    elif len(s) == 1:
        return True
    elif len(s) > 1:
        if s[0] == s[-1]:
            return palindrome(s[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
```

When the palindrome has an odd number of letters (e.g. racecar) it works, but when the palindrome has an even number of letters (e.g. daad) it returns False.

Can someone help me identify my mistake in the code?

Comment: `if len(s) == 0: return False` is the problem. In this case you nee the empty string to return True. Think about what happens with a 2 character string like "aa".

Answer (score 0):

When the string is empty, it **is** a palindrome, you need that condition for `daad`

```
"daad" => d==d && "aa" => a==a && ""
```

So first 2 conditions can me merge in `if len(s) <= 1`, and you can remove the `else` because each branch has a `return` statement

```
def palindrome(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    if s[0] == s[-1]:
        return palindrome(s[1:-1])
    return False
```

---

Using boolean expressions, you can shorten into a one-liner

```
def palindrome(s):
    return len(s) <= 1 or s[0] == s[-1] and palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Comment: Just a small note for those who like one-liners, you can actually shorten the function to this:
`def palindrome(s): return len(s) <= 1 or s[0] == s[-1] and palindrome(s[1:-1])`